# Working with systems with Perfect Multicollinearity

Tags: r, time-series, regression, multicollinearity

I am working with a time-series dataset that is based on demand-supply dynamics with variables: Production, Ending Stocks, Exports, Imports etc. I was working on a regression with this data and wanted to find the relative importance of regressors using `relaimpo` package in R. However, I soon realized I can't use regression setting because of near to perfect collinearity in my dataset - the standard errors will be inflated and hence will be the relative importance of each regressor. Is there a way to go around this? Or, can I use any other method (instead of regression)? Any suggestions will be useful.